# How to make GNOME/Ubuntu app switcher behave like OS X wrt applications vs. windows?

Tags: macos, ubuntu, gnome

I started doing most of my development on my Mac OS X notebook, and I got really used to the keyboard setup.

Anyway, specifically, I'd like alt (or super) + tab to switch between apps, not windows, and alt+` to rotate through application windows.  Is that possible, or is it not really possible with the current Xorg + window manager setup Linux has?

Answer (score 2):

The following worked for me on Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS:

1. Install compizconfig-settings-manager
2. Open it
3. Select the "Desktop" category
4. Select "Ubuntu Unity Plugin"
5. Navigate to the Switcher tab
6. Check the box labeled "Switcher strictly changes between applications"

If the only windows open belong to those of the same application, alt-tab will still switch between them.

Answer (score 0):

GNOME 3 behaves as you ask. If you would like to customize metacity, go to System/Preferences/Keyboard shortcuts.  However, for GNOME <= 2.32 there are two options: move between windows and move between windows of the same application.